# Qt: Load HTML source code to string

Tags: c++, qt

I have an HTML file stored locally that I have to extract text from.

Now I managed to prompt the user for the location and display the HTML file in a QTextBrowser by pressing a button. Now from what I understand the next step would be to convert to a string to be able to search for text inside the source code.

Here's my Button_clicked method so far

```
void MainWindow::on_getHTMLButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename = openFilenameDialog();

    if (filename.isEmpty())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("File Name"), "Es wurde keine gültige Datei angegeben.");
    }
    else
    {
        QFile file(filename);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
            QMessageBox::information(0, "Info", file.errorString());
        }
        else
        {
            QTextStream in(&file);
            ui->textBrowserHTML->setText(in.readAll());
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML file shows in textBrowser without any issues.
My understanding so far is that I need to create a string to search for a substring in the source code.
Now my problem is that I cannot seem to create a string object with the source of the HTML file as content.
Something like

```
QString string = in.readAll();
```

does not seem to work...

Comment: What is the problem actually ?

Comment: You passed the string via setText()

Comment: Did an update to make more clear what my problem is – sorry for not being   more clear in the first draft of the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to learn that after having read out the stream and putting it to the ui by

`ui->textBrowserHTML->setText(in.readAll());`

the stream is empty – so when I attempt to to do a readAllagain it results in an empty string.